# how to use the array of objects returned by a method java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Method 1 of different class:

```
public train[] search_train()
{
    int i=1;
    try
    { 
        String sql="select * from train ";
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
             t[i]= new train();
             t[i].train_id=rs.getInt("TRAIN_ID");
             i++;          
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return t;
}
```

Method 2 (taking the array of objects):

```
train t[]= new train[20];
t=d.search();
System.out.print(t[2].no);`
```

Prints a null value.

Comment: Post the full (and real) relevant code ;)

Comment: First of all, there is no point in instantiating `t` before calling `search()` because you are instantiating and returning an array inside `search()` already. Secondly, show us your entire loop code and perhaps we can point you in the right direction

Comment: `public train[] search_train()
    {int i=1;    try
     { String sql="select * from train ";
         rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                 while(rs.next()){
                 t[i]= new train();
                 t[i].train_id=rs.getInt("TRAIN_ID");
                 i++;
         }         
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return t;
    }`

Comment: @Umer Ahasn - Java arrays are zero-indexed, so you should start your loop with `int i = 0;`

Comment: @UmerAhsan Please edit any additional code into the original question, rather than posting it in the comments.

Comment: @Umer please don't edit the question to be correct (`int i=0`), it ruins the whole point of it being here. Leave it incorrect (`int i=1`) and add an answer saying what fixed it instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the solution was fixing the array indexing.

I want to add, too, Java naming conventions prefer capitalized object names. `train` -> `Train`, in this case, and CamelCase method names, or `searchTrain`. Though, it looks like this method should be called `getTrains` since there is no searching in this code-block.

```
public train[] search_train() {
  int i=0; // <--- Java arrays are zero-indexed
  try { 
    String sql="select * from train "; 
    rs=st.executeQuery(sql); 
    while(rs.next()){ 
      t[i]= new train(); 
      t[i].train_id=rs.getInt("TRAIN_ID"); 
      i++; 
    } 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
  return t; 
}
```